# append X,Y,Z and intensity values into a las file

Tags: python, las, pdal, laspy

I want to append XYZI values row after row into a las file.How to do this?
I'm using python laspy library to write XYZI points at once, but i want to append row after row using a loop.

The points are in SQLite db I need to generate a .LAS file(v1.3 and v1.4).I get memory error as the db grows large.

i'm doing this

import laspy

header = laspy.header.Header()
outfile = laspy.file.File("output.las", mode="w", header=header)
outfile.X = *read column1 from db*
outfile.Y = *read coulmn2 from db*
outfile.Z = *read column3 from db*

outfile.close()

Comment: Which software do you want to use? Do you require it to be row after row really? Does it have to be from within Python code? Bit more information would be a good idea :)

Comment: @bugmenot123 is there anyway to write millions(las file of size 15gb) of points at once ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "at once". If it is really just converting XYZI to LAS, I would use the las2las tool.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here. I have to write a script to read points from SQLite db and create a .LAS file.

Comment: Ah, that makes it clearer. Hm, sadly the laspy documentation does not cover a case like that. Maybe ask on their https://github.com/laspy/laspy/issues/ ? With pdal this looks promising https://pdal.io/stages/readers.sqlite.html but also leaves a lot to guess/read. Good luck and if you find a way, remember to post it here! Hopefully someone can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yogi,You can check here -https://github.com/laspy/laspy/commit/4dba4c846eacf119b5e99ccf8ccae73735ef1944.   You need to write the points to an numpy array first and then write the array(X's, y's and Z's) to the file.

Read a few million points at a time and make smaller las files that you can eventually join together to make a much more massive file.

If you make smaller "tiles" you can merge them with Whiteboxtools LidarJoin - https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/lidar_tools.html#LidarJoin.

Comment: Thank you @Cary H I have done the same and used python-pdal library to merge